# I want a user to press a button to select the time before NStimer fires

Tags: ios

i am pretty much a noob here  , and even writing the title was pretty hard ...but here goes

I am trying to get my app to do this
1) user presses a button
2) the button converts the press to an int value
3) the value is then passed to NStimer and the timer counts until the int value is reached ( ie 30 secs if int value is 30
4) the program changes the image on the screen

I have got it to fire off the NStimer and change the screen by using a variable button and by changing this value manually i can set the timer to go off after different times

What i cant do is to get the timer to fire after the value is changed by the pressing of the button.
If i use NSLog i can see the value is changing but doesnt affect NSTimer....any ideas

Sorry if thats a bit long winded ,but here is the code...
Any help would be awesome...as i have lost most of my hair trying to work this out with do while loops and if statements

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    UIImageView *theImage;
    int imageCount;
    int button;
    button = 10;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *theImage;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *press;


@end

//
//  ViewController.m
//  use ns timer to display an image
//
//  Created by Clive Dancey on 19/02/2013.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Clive Dancey. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"



@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label1;


@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:button
                                     target:self
                                     selector:@selector(animateFunction)
                                     userInfo:nil
                                     repeats:YES];
}

- (IBAction)press:(id)sender
{
    button = 1;
}

- (void)animateFunction
{
    NSLog(@"Timer heartbeat %i", button);
    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"EZDecline.png"];
    [_theImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Your timer is "forgotten"... I'd use a variable `NSTimer myTimer` in the `.h`, and then start it: `myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval...]`;
When button is pressed, I'd invalidate (`[myTimer invalidate]` it and start it again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got you,

1) remove this from viewDidLoad

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:button
                             target:self
                             selector:@selector(animateFunction)
                             userInfo:nil
                             repeats:YES];
```

2) Add this line to .h file

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer *myTimer;
```

3) Change the code in your button press event, (like this)

```
- (IBAction)press:(id)sender {
button=1;
if(_myTimer) [_myTimer invalidate];
_myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:button
                             target:self
                             selector:@selector(animateFunction)
                             userInfo:nil
                             repeats:YES];
```

}